# Swift remote push notifications, how do I actually trigger them to be sent?

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently working on developing an app in swift 5, Xcode 11, and I am getting towards the end of the initial development. Right now, I am attempting to integrate Remote Push Notifications into the app. I have followed a lot of tutorials online and it works in the sense that I can send the remote notifications through the "Pusher" app, but this is only for testing purposes. I can't seem to find anything about how to actually trigger the notifications through the code, so that, for example, if a user were to receive a message in the app, they would get a push notification. I am not sure if I am just completely missing something, but if anyone can explain to me what exactly I am skimming over in simple terms, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Remote push notifications are called “remote” because they are typically sent from your server to the Apple Push Notification Service (another server), and from there - to the users whom you targeted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we talk about "remote notifications", it means that we have a server that sends us these notifications. As I understand, you want to just show in-app banner that looks like notification. You have 2 options:

1. Follow [these instructions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app) and schedule notifications locally
2. Use some sort of third party library (e.g. [SwiftEntryKit](https://github.com/huri000/SwiftEntryKit)) to create customized in-app notifications.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I will look into those.